# Not able to connect to MySQL - Glassfish and Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, glassfish

I have the below `persistence` file -

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="unit" >
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="pwd" />
```

Now, when I deploy this on glassfish - generate logs as below -

```
HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: application
...]
HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.2.Final}
HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Warning: RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool DerbyPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Warning: RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ DerbyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Warning: RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.]
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Info: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Info: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
Info: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Info: Loading application [application] at [/application]
Info: application was successfully deployed in 14,905 milliseconds.
```

Why does glassfish complains about **derby**? I'm not using it.

And, when I try to access a rest service -which internally goes for entitymanager - I get the below stacktrace --

```
2016-10-03T12:41:03.337+0530|Info: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: unit
...]
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Info: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db]
Info: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=user, password=****}
Info: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Info: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Info: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Info: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Info: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Info: not null  <<<<<<---------- this is my EntityManager instance which is not null
Warning: RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool DerbyPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Warning: RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ DerbyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Warning: RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.]
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
ERROR: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
ERROR: HHH000337: Unable to mark for rollback on PersistenceException: 
org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaPlatformInaccessibleException: Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.makePhysicalTransactionDelegate(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:229)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.getTransactionDriverControl(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:203)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.<init>(TransactionImpl.java:37)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.accessTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:372)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.markForRollbackOnly(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:342)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.handlePersistenceException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:271)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:148)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1407)
at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:417)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.QueryWrapper.getResultList(QueryWrapper.java:84)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.TypedQueryWrapper.getResultList(TypedQueryWrapper.java:73)
at RESTClass.findAll(RESTClass.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1681)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Warning: StandardWrapperValve[rest_servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet rest_servlet threw exception
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:271)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetAgent.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.newAgent_(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.initConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl40.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientBaseDataSourceRoot.getConnectionX(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientBaseDataSourceRoot.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1189)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1512)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:944)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:230)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:511)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:171)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:147)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:99)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:129)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1940)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1909)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1458)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1426)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1398)
at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:417)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.QueryWrapper.getResultList(QueryWrapper.java:84)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.TypedQueryWrapper.getResultList(TypedQueryWrapper.java:73)
at com.accountpro.entity.service.AbstractFacade.findAll(AbstractFacade.java:43)
at com.accountpro.entity.service.CityFacadeREST.findAll(CityFacadeREST.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1681)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can someone hazard a guess...like what could be wrong? I am trying to use built in connection pooling which comes with hibernate.

Update - 
Below is how am injecting the EntityManager in one of my service class

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "unit")
private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: FWIW Some Hibernate-specific config file is not part of JPA. You only need persistence.xml

Comment: @NeilStockton Thanks. Learning JPA and hibernate. Will get rid of the cfg file.

Comment: Please show us the code where you retrieve your entity manager or your session.

Comment: Is your Glasfish a fresh installation?

Comment: @PaulWasilewski Yes, I'm using Payara latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `JTA` typed resource then you have to declare your database in your application server. In this case your transactions are managed by your app server and you can inject your `entityManager` through the `PersitenceContext`.

If you want to have a database which is not declared in your application server only in your `persistence.xml` (like you did it) then you have to use `persistence-unit-type=RESOURCE_LOCAL`. To retrieve your `entityManager` in this scenario you have to use a `PersistenceUnit` and get it through a `EntityManagerFactory`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the following line in the stacktrace

> ERROR: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.

you can guess what the problem can be. The first problem is the database driver issue I think. `1527` is the default port number of derby database which is shipped with the Glassfish application server.

As you haven't provided any datasource in your configuration the server is trying to find the default database which is derby in this case; but you cannot connect to that database as you haven't provided any connection informations for this database.

So you have to do the following in your `META-INF/persistence.xml`:

- Provide the `transaction-type` (in your config it is assumed to be JTA because you're deploying your application on JEE environment per specification) as

  ```
  <persistence-unit name="unit" transaction-type="JTA">
  ```
- Provide the `jta-data-source` element as a child of `persistence-unit`

  ```
  <persistence-unit name="unit" transaction-type="JTA">
      ...
      <jta-data-source>your_data_source_name</jta-data-source>
      ...
  </persistence-unit>
  ```

In order for the above configuration to work you have to configure your application server (Glassfish) frist. To do so you have to download the MySQL jdbc driver, unpack it and copy the jar file into `<glassfish_installation_directory>/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib` (I am assuming here Glassfish 3.1). The reason for this is that Glassfish is not shipped with MySQL driver, so you have to do this yourself.

After this start Glassfish and open the admin console (http://localhost:4848). On the left pane open

1. `Resources/JDBC/JDBC Connection Pools` and create a new connection pool
2. `Resources/JDBC/JDBC Resources` and create a new datasource. The name you give to your datasource is the one you have to in your `persistence.xml` as mentioned above.