# Dependency injection by annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

**PersistenceContext** and **Autowire** dependency injection annotations are not working. I get NullPointerException. I have gone around the issue by creating getEntityManager and getDaoInstance methods in their respective Abstract class. However, still, I wish to figure out/understand why the annotations will not work in the first place.

I looked at related contents on StackOverflow, but I had had little luck.

- [Spring dependency injection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573884/spring-dependency-injection-not-working)
- [Inject a EntityManagerFactory through @PersitenceContext or @PersitenceUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503504/inject-a-entitymanagerfactory-through-persitencecontext-or-persitenceunit)
- [Not able to connect to MySQL - Glassfish and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826411/not-able-to-connect-to-mysql-glassfish-and-hibernate/39829975#39829975)

**PS:** I am **new** to Java

**AbstractDao** class with getEntityManager method (Full code, https://pastebin.com/6nKh1ujY)

```
package com.beetlehand.model.dao;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public abstract class AbstractDao<T, S> implements AbstractDaoInterface<T, S> {

    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if(this.entityManager == null) {
            this.entityManager = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit")
                .createEntityManager();
        }

        return this.entityManager;
    }
    
    // more code below
    
 }
```

Example of how **getEntityManager** method called in Dao class (Full code, https://pastebin.com/dhjz17sN)

```
package com.beetlehand.model.dao;

import com.beetlehand.model.AttributeEntity;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class AttributeDao extends AbstractDao<AttributeEntity, Integer> {

    public AttributeEntity getById(Integer id) {
        if(id == null) return null;
        return getEntityManager().find(AttributeEntity.class, id);
    }
    
    // more code below
    
 }
```

**AbstractService** with getDaoInstance method (Full code, https://pastebin.com/H4HGB43y)

```
package com.beetlehand.model.service;

import com.beetlehand.model.dao.AbstractDaoInterface;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class AbstractService {

    protected HashMap<String, Object> daoInstance = new HashMap<>();

    public AbstractDaoInterface getDaoInstance(String className) {
        try {
            if(!daoInstance.containsKey(className)) {
                className = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(className, new char[]{'_'})
                        .replaceAll("_", "");
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.beetlehand.model.dao." + className);
                Constructor<?> ctr = clazz.getConstructor();
                daoInstance.put(className, ctr.newInstance());
            }
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }

        return (AbstractDaoInterface) daoInstance.get(className);
    }
}
```

Example of how **getDaoInstance** method called in Service class (Full code, https://pastebin.com/86yNSmsX)

```
package com.beetlehand.model.service;

import com.beetlehand.model.*;
import com.beetlehand.model.dao.AbstractDaoInterface;

public class CatalogService extends AbstractService {

    public AttributeEntity addAttribute(AttributeEntity attributeEntity) {
        AbstractDaoInterface attributeDao = this.getDaoInstance("attribute_dao");
        attributeDao.saveRow(attributeEntity);

        return attributeEntity;
    }

    public AttributeValueEntity addAttributeValue(AttributeValueEntity attributeValueEntity) {
       AbstractDaoInterface attributeValueDao = this.getDaoInstance("attribute_value_dao") ;
       attributeValueDao.saveRow(attributeValueEntity);

       return attributeValueEntity;
    }
    
    // more code below
    
 }
```

Comment: (1) you posted three concrete classes inside which you hope for DI to work, but neither of them is annotated with `@Component/@Service/@Repository`. How do you create your beans? (2) I understand you're not using Spring Boot? Please post your `XxxEntityManagerFactoryBean` configuration

Comment: First: Use @Service annotation on your service. It is make a singleton when your app is booting. And you can use as dependency like construct autowire methodic.